# Objective-C: Grid View in iPad issue in removing the object

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uibutton, uilabel

I have a view where I am showing image and image name in a grid view. As shown in the image.

[image: show image]

Now for the same I am taking one UIButton with image as background and UILabel and positioning it accordingly on the screen. Now when I press on the UIButton, it shows the UIActionSheet with option to delete, view and cancel. Now problem comes here. When I press Delete for only one record, the record gets deleted, but if more that one records are there, then gives issues in deleting that it shows the deleted record.

**To Add UIButton and UILabel:**

```
-(void)showImageFrame
{
    int FrameWidth = 190;
    int Frameheight = 196;
    int FrameX;
    int FrameY;

    int lblWidth = 190;
    int lblHeight = 40;
    int lblX,lblY;

    settButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [settButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Picture frame.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [settButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pressSelectedImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    btnInnerImg = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [btnInnerImg addTarget:self action:@selector(pressSelectedImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    lblImgName = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    lblImgName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30];
    lblImgName.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lblImgName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblImgName.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    for(int i = 0;i<cnt1;i++)
    {
        [settButton setTag:i];
        img = [[appDelegate.DataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"ProfileImage"];

        [btnInnerImg setImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btnInnerImg setTag:i];

        lblImgName.text = [[appDelegate.DataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"strNameImg"];
        [lblImgName setTag:i];

        if(i==0)
        {
            FrameX = 35;FrameY = 119;btnX = 49;btnY=134;lblX = 35;lblY=337;
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            FrameX = 289;FrameY = 119;btnX = 303;btnY=134;lblX = 289;lblY=337;
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            FrameX = 545;FrameY = 119;lblX = 545;lblY=337;btnX = 558;btnY=134;
        }
        if(i==3)
        {
            FrameX = 802;FrameY = 119;lblX = 802;lblY=337;btnX = 816;btnY=134;
        }
        if(i==4)
        {
            FrameX = 35;FrameY = 411;lblX = 35;lblY=629;btnX = 49;btnY=426;
        }
        if(i==5)
        {
            FrameX = 289;FrameY = 411;lblX = 289;lblY=629;btnX = 303;btnY=426;
        }
        if(i==6)
        { 
            FrameX = 545;FrameY = 411;lblX = 545;lblY=629;btnX = 558;btnY=426;
        }
        if(i==7)
        {
            FrameX = 802;FrameY = 411;lblX = 802;lblY=629;btnX = 816;btnY=426;
        }

        [settButton setFrame:CGRectMake(FrameX,FrameY,FrameWidth,Frameheight)];
        [lblImgName setFrame:CGRectMake(lblX,lblY,lblWidth,lblHeight)];
        [btnInnerImg setFrame:CGRectMake(btnX,btnY,btnWidth,btnHeight)];

        [newButtonArray addObject:settButton];
        [self.view addSubview: settButton];
        [self.view addSubview: lblImgName];
        [self.view addSubview: btnInnerImg];
    }
}
```

**To remove the UIButton and UILabel:**

```
-(void)removeImageFrame
{
    [settButton removeFromSuperview];
    [btnInnerImg removeFromSuperview];
    [lblImgName removeFromSuperview];

    settButton = nil;
    btnInnerImg = nil;
    lblImgName = nil;        
}
```

I don't want to use UITableviewCell for the grid view. Also what I am doing is that on deleting 1 record, I am removing all the records and reload them again as per record counter. I know I am doing some mistake in `removeImageFrame` method, but not able to find it. How can I remove the single UIButton with different Tags?

Comment: Does this even display the grid properly? You are creating a single button and then altering its properties and repeatedly adding it to the superview.

Comment: yes it is showing perfectly. also when there is only one record,it deleted the same nicely. Problem occurs only when there are more that one record.

Comment: is there any other way to deal with the same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice to see a bit more context (the action method and how you get from pressing the button to deleting the button), but here is some advice:

- Remove all objects from your button array at the start of showImageFrame
- Create new buttons (with locally declared variables, not an ivar) inside the loop.
- Don't use a tag of 0, that is the default tag that all views have
- When a button is tapped, try to pass this as an argument to the removeImageFrame method - that's what `sender` is for.
- You could also look at background images and foreground images for a single button instead of having what appears to be one button for the frame and one for a picture
- (unrelated to your problem) try to think of a better way to display a grid than hard coding coordinates. What it the device is rotated?

Comment: I guess you are right. I don't know why i did such poor coding. :( anyways thank you for your tips. I would follow them and +1 for your support. Thank you.